# Calling javascript functions with a link click using C# and WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, invokescript

I want to emulate clicking a link of a third-party site

> a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$find('ct100_m_g_02foobar').exportReport('XML');"

In C#, I am using a WebBrowser WinForms control.

> var x = webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("find", new object[] { "ct100_m_g_02foobar" });

I'm not familiar with JavaScript, but I imagine I need to tie in the results of the find function with the exportReport function. What call would I need to do to emulate the above link? My x variable is null so I'm not even sure if I'm even on the right track with this InvokeScript. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of looks like what you are looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx

HTH,
Richard